# How to change codeigniter post permalink as WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter

This is is the current Blog Post Details URL.

```
site.com/blog/details/this-is-a-blog-post
```

But, I want my Blog Post URL like this.

```
site.com/blog/this-is-a-blog-post
```

I'm using CodeIgniter framework right now. Is there any way to do this in CI by anyway?

Thank you.

Comment: I solved the problem using Codeigniter Routes. 

I added a new route to application/config/routes.php

`$route['blog/(:any)'] = "blog/details/$1";`

Comment: If you solved your own problem, please consider adding it as an answer, and marking it as correct -- This clears the question from the queue, and even awards reputation to you :)

Comment: Sorry bro, i cant find a way to do it as correct.  Can please show me how to do it? @ObsidianAge

Comment: You need to first re-write your comment as an answer in a box at the bottom of the page. Then you'll see a checkbox that you can tick on the left-hand side, just below the vote buttons. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using Codeigniter Routes. I added a new route to application/config/routes.php $route['blog/(:any)'] = "blog/details/$1";